# How to retrieve large strings over TCP using Streamreader

Tags: c#, tcpclient, streamreader

I'm trying to receive large strings over TCP, I tried various methods, but none of them worked as good as this one (which is quite simple actually).

```
public partial class MyClass : Form
{
    Int64 counter;
    StreamWriter writer;
    StreamReader reader;

    public MyClass(object streamIn, object StreamOut)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.Black;
        richTextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Gray;


        writer = (StreamWriter)streamIn;
        reader = (StreamReader)StreamOut;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            JObject o = new JObject();
            char[] buffer = new char[1024];
            int count = buffer.Length;

            o.Add("comando", 15);
            o.Add("filename", textBox2.Text);
            o.Add("param", textBox3.Text);

            writer.Write(o.ToString());
            writer.Flush();

            richTextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

The problem using this is that I have to close the stream on the other end, in order for this to read. There is any way I can use `reader.ReadToEnd()` without having to close the stream on the other end after sending and therefore closing the connection between  client-server?

Comment: Would you be so kind as to add the code that declares and initializes `reader` and `writer`?

Comment: I doubt yu can make `ReadToend` to read *not* till the end. That said, there is nothing magical about it and other `Read` methods should perform similarly. What problem are you running into exactly?

Comment: @Miserable Variable: When using other methods, such as `Read` and `ReadLine` my app crashes (even in debug, no erros, exceptions...) when trying to read the `StreamReader` when there isn't anything else to be read. I even tried to get the number of bytes read so if it's 0 I know its finished, but it crashes just as I it tries to read when there is nothing to be read.

Comment: You might want to create a separate question so experts can help you with that. If `Read*` make your app crash, it is almost certainly usage error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the Basic Example for the network library [networkcomms.net](http://www.networkcomms.net) which is covered in the [Getting Started](http://www.networkcomms.net/getting-started/) article. Although this is a console example it allows you to send arbitrary length strings.

Your example looks like it might be a winform application. There is also a [WPF chat application](http://www.networkcomms.net/creating-a-wpf-chat-client-server-application/) example if that is of interest.